# Не могу распарсить JSON, проблема в том как сделать структуру по нее

Tags: json, swift, парсер

Как распрасить такое? Пытался через кодабл, но тут меня сильно смущает первый "data" внутри которого получается лежат три разных объекта, вот тут то и проблемы начинаются (у меня), обычные json парсятся легко, может есть примеры кода подобного этому, все никак не могу разобраться:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "name": "title",
            "data": {
                "text": "SomeText»"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "picture",
            "data": {
                "url": "someUrl",
                "text": "text"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "selector",
            "data": {
                "selectedId": 1,
                "variants": [{
                        "id": 0,
                        "text": "text1"
                    }, {
                        "id": 1,
                        "text": "text2"
                    }, {
                        "id": 2,
                        "text": "text3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "view": ["title", "selector", "picture", "title"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю вам воспользоваться этим ресурсом:
https://app.quicktype.io/
Вот пример того, что получилось:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
    let view: [String]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let name: String
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let text, url: String?
    let selectedID: Int?
    let variants: [Variant]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text, url
        case selectedID = "selectedId"
        case variants
    }
}

// MARK: - Variant
struct Variant: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let text: String
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло, как раз пытался именно так спарить)